# Unable to receive Device Access events

Tags: nest-device-access

I've enabled events for my project in the Device Access Console and provided a Pub/Sub topic, but I'm not receiving them. I am able to successfully authorize accounts and list devices for the authorized user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After events are enabled through the Device Access Console, you must initiate them using a [one-time call to list devices](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/subscribe-to-events#initiate_events) after you receive an access token for each authorized account. This initial call finishes the authorization process and enables events to be sent to your Pub/Sub subscription.

For example, a simple cURL call like this will initiate events:

```
curl -X GET 'https://smartdevicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/enterprises/[project-id]/devices' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer my-access-token'
```